# Horizontally center a div with a fixed position

Tags: html, css

In the following code, how do I horizontally center a div with a fixed position? I've tried several things, but none will get it right in the center.

I'm trying to get the div at 100px from the top, and horizontally centered.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>
<style type="text/css">
.myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:auto;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="myDiv">Something went wrong. God save the Queen!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tried left: 50%; or anything?

Comment: I did, but it's still not in the center (I'm using Firefox right now).

Comment: You need to put a negative margin on it, that is half the width of the div.  Then it will be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
left  : 25%;
right : 25%;
```

<kbd>[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/y439y/)</kbd>

Comment: It actually the same as fixing its width to `50%`. He might want to define it alternatively.

Comment: Not in the question, but you may be right. Then @FabrizioCalderan solution is not overkill anymore, and should be used. Center of the screen minus Half of the item.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't know in advance the width of your div (or if you can't set it) you may use the `transform` property:

```
.myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    ...
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Example code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fqpwd

Comment: This one is pretty great ! But `CSS3` is needed.

Comment: It works on all modern browser. And for older browser (IE<9) you could use a different style/graceful degradation (e.g. `width: 50%`) through conditional comments

Comment: Browsers might, but [flying saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) does not unfortunately. I did not find any CSS 2.1 solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/D9q2w/1/)

You should set the width, so you can use this in HTML.

```
<div id="centerme">I'm a div and I wanna stay in the center!</div>
```

and this for CSS.

```
#centerme{
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;   
        background:red;
        width:250px;
        height:60px;
    }
```

PS: like you can see if you set the height you can center it vertically too ;) (but you don't need it :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you div has specific width try to add this:

```
width: somevalue;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -somevalue/2;
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/NZX38/

Answer (score 0):

If you fix it's width, with any value (can be percentage), you can do it like this :

```
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px; /* 250 / 2 */
```

If you go with percentages, it's even simpler :

```
width: 50%;
position: fixed;
left: 25%; /* (100 - width) / 2 */
```

Working fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqF2P/)

Comment: @Danko No, as you can see in my fiddle. Not with `position: fixed`. There are some cases where you want this positionning and still want it to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2SRAe/1/)**

**The HTML Code:**

```
<div class="myDiv">Something went wrong. God save the Queen!</div>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
.myDiv {
   background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    width: calc(100% - 37px);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic jquery code for center the div

HTML:

```
    <p><button id="button1">click and center the div</button></p>
    <p class="centerDiv"></p>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        function movediv(){
          win_width=$(window).width();
          win_height=$(window).height();
          div_width=$('.centerDiv').width();
          div_height=$('.centerDiv').height();
          $('.centerDiv').css('top',(win_height/2)-(div_height/2)).css('left',(win_width/2)-(div_width/2)).toggle();
        }
        movediv();
        $(window).resize(function(){
    movediv();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
   .centerDiv{
       background-color:red;
       position:absolute;
       width:200px;
       height:100px;
    }
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/2SRAe/7/)**

Comment: javascript should be avoided when not necessary and if easier css solutions exist.